# Maximum value of a variable in system of two equations

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Consider the system of equations

$$ 3a + 2b + c+ d =14 $$
$$ a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2} =14.$$

Is there any way to find maximum value of $d$ using AM-GM inequality. I am not even able to think, how to start approaching this problem.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d \ge 0$?

Comment: No, these are any real numbers.

Comment: Using Cauchy-Schwarz (or with AM-GM after expanding if you want): $(3a+2b+c)^2 \leq 14(a^2+b^2+c^2) \implies (14-d)^2 \leq 14(14-d^2)$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Can we say $d \le \frac{28}{15}$?

Comment: @Math__Nerd yes, that's the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a brilliant use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @LHF, can you turn your comment into an answer? I am unable to see how you got there.